# Replacing variables in yaml files from gradle.properies

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-functions

I have .env.yaml file with following

```
CLIENTID: ${project.ClientId}
CLIENTSECRET: ${project.ClientSecret}
```

and in gradle.properties

```
clientId=myId
clientId=mySecret
```

Is there way I can replace the variables in .env.yaml with the properties in gradle.properties before deployment like following ?

```
./gradlew clean deploy
```

Comment: is `.env.yaml` copied in any way ?

Comment: I could keep a .env.yaml.template but the final position is same where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a template file, and during the deployment copy it over to the final destination. You can [configure the copy task to expand](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:expand(java.util.Map)) the copied file with the given variables.

The copy task would look something like this:

```
task deploy(type: Copy) {
    from '.env.yaml.template'
    rename '.*', '.env.yaml'
    destinationDir projectDir
    expand project: project
}
```

Comment: `expand project: project.properties`